Gravity Forms Wordpress is deleting the inputs on error
I am using an embedded Gravity forms Elementor form with AJAX enabled.
I noticed that when the user fills out the form, submits it and there is an error, all the previously submitted inputs are deleted!
How can I change this behaviour and always preserve already inputted fields?
Thanks!

Which theme and which plugin version you are using?

Hello Elementor theme, Gravity Forms Version 2.8.18, Elementor Pro Version 3.24.4
